# When I do command as "npm install" it comes npm ERR code ENOENT npm ERR

Tags: reactjs, json, npm, installation, node-modules

npm ERR! code ENOENT npm ERR! syscall open npm ERR! path C:\Users\hp\Downloads\Direct-messaging-app-app/package.json npm ERR! errno -4058 npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\hp\Downloads\Direct-messaging-app-app\package.json' npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file. npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR! C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-11-24T06_46_21_615Z-debug-0.log

[this is the problem, because of this I cant command npm Install Npm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5sOy.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you in the right folder?? because it seems like you running the npm in Direct-messaging-app-app folder and npm not able to find the package.json file in it , that's why you getting this error I think

you need to be in chat-app folder or where your package.json file is , to run the npm command