# What's causing the npm ERR ! code ENOENT error when I try to start a react project on Windows?

Tags: reactjs, npm, npx

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\WINDOWS\system32/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\EMİR\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-05-27T08_41_38_142Z-debug-0.log

I try the start react project in my computer. But i can't...
It's give me ERR like this...

Comment: What's the command you use? In which directory you execute it? What's your npm version?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When I do command as "npm install" it comes npm ERR code ENOENT npm ERR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74569200/when-i-do-command-as-npm-install-it-comes-npm-err-code-enoent-npm-err)

Comment: Main err is ('create-react-app' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.) this

Comment: If i write npm create- its give me not recognized err / if i write npx create- gives me To see a list of supported npm commands, run:
  npm help

Comment: According to my research there is a problem with the path and I need to fix it...

Comment: @OrkWard v18.16.0

Comment: @abolfazlshamsollahi I write